# Call Js Function onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

Is there any way to call a Javascript function from a mouse over in HTML?

I have the following code:

```
<script src="navSound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a href="#" onmouseover="bubble2.playclip()"><li class="navBackground"><div class="navButton">Gallery</div></li></a>
```

I would like it to call a function named "playclip()" which is in an external file linked to the HTML document named navSound.js

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably silly question, but did you import the external script correctly? can you call the function without the mouseover, like on page load or something? Also i believe you do not need the () afterplayclip. dont think it hurts though

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console log? `F12` in whatever browser.

Comment: Why is there a link there? It doesn't go anywhere and it isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you for replying. This comment should address all of your questions: I do not see any errors or warnings in my browser console log. Right now, the link purposely does not lead anywhere, as once I finish the prototype page with the new navigaiton, I will add in the filenames in the href. I believe the script has been imported correctly, here is my import statement:     <script src="navSound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible like so:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function playclip() {
    alert('playing clip...');
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onmouseover="playclip()"><li class="navBackground"><div class="navButton">Gallery</div></li></a>

</body>
</html>
```

In your case, the playclip() function will be inside the external file "navSound.js" included in the script tag using the 'src' attribute.

**UPDATE:**

I updated your Fiddle with and you can see the changes here which work well:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb966/ (beware: you'd hear a horse's neiggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhh ;)

I am also pasting the markup + code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

window.onload = function() {

    var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
        "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
        "mp4": "audio/mp4",
        "ogg": "audio/ogg",
        "wav": "audio/wav"
    }

    function createsoundbite(sound){
        var html5audio=document.createElement('audio');
        if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
            for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
                var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
                sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
                if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                    sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
                html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
            }
            html5audio.load()
            html5audio.playclip=function(){
                //html5audio.pause()
                html5audio.currentTime=0
                html5audio.play()
            }
            return html5audio
        }
        else{
            return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
        }
    }

    var audio = createsoundbite("http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg");
    audio.setAttribute('id', 'myAudio');
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(audio);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'></div>
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myAudio').play()">Gallery</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, this does not seem to work. Could it be because it passes in a parameter of the sound? Here is the javascript file that I am trying to load (bubble2) http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/x4MN7/

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working example as per your requirements. the code is self explanatory, but please let me know if anything is not clear

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. Do you also know of a way to play 2 different sounds (depending on the nav item)? Would I have a string of the file name that gets passed into the file?

Comment: you're welcome Jake. If I understand you correctly, then Yes, you can play different sounds for different nav items. You just have to create the respective audio elements and set their IDs to call them from onmouseover event as I did.

Comment: Thanks for replying. After attempting to use this, I am getting an error in the console:n [Error] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('content').appendChild') (navSound.js, line 43) Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand from your comment. Perhaps post a jsfiddle to your current code so I can have a look?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Here is an updated JSFiddle with the problem. If you run the fiddle and look at your browser's console, you can see the error. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/B944P/ Any ideas about what is going on?

Comment: Hi Jake. Unfortunately, your fiddle is way off from the code in my answer. Try and see what is different and what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all of your help debugging this issue.